# Looking for Kineticjs Resources

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, 2d-games

I am looking for Kineticjs Resources ( except the official kineticjs site) - books , blogs , sample projects with source. There are several projects published on the official kineticjs site but i wasn't able to find the source code of any of them.

Comment: The KineticJS tutorial site is quite good: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/  Also you can click on the kineticjs tag here on stackoverflow and see what other kineticjs learners are asking/being answered.

Comment: Stack overflow is not the place to ask such references, this is not an appropriate question type. Please read about & help sections for more details

Comment: @Ani, I have a mixed opinion.  On the one hand, SO is clearly a forum for specific programming questions rather than a "where can I get info" site.  On the other hand, SO is frequented by people like you and me who have the knowledge to easily point "first time questioners" in a good direction.  It's sometimes my choice to "close" such off-topic questions by first-timers...but to also help those first-timers with a comment or even an answer.  So, call me a rebel against the rules!

Comment: @markE I agree with your reasoning but resources can very well be found using Google. For instance, if you search for KineticJS, html5canvastutorials.com is among the top results. The very reason such questions are avoided on SO is that it can lead to very opinionated answers and long discussions but may be for niche topics like this, it does not apply so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just trying to organize such useful stuff: https://github.com/lavrton/kineticjs-tips-and-tools

Comment: Thanks , it was exactly what i have been looking for